# How to group subsequent objects of an array in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this array of objects:

```js
[
    {
        key1: "AAA",
        key2: "BBB"
    },
    {
        key1: "BBB",
        key2: "CCC"
    },
    {
        key1: "CCC",
        key2: "DDD"
    },
    {
        key1: "XXX",
        key2: "YYY"
    },
]
```

How does one write a concise function to group them, so that if the `key1` of the next object is equal to the `key2` of the previous, the subsequent objects will become one?

The desired output of the above example:

```js
[
    {
        key1: "AAA",
        key2: "DDD"
    },
    {
        key1: "XXX",
        key2: "YYY"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce`:

```js
const input = [
    {
        key1: "AAA",
        key2: "BBB"
    },
    {
        key1: "BBB",
        key2: "CCC"
    },
    {
        key1: "CCC",
        key2: "DDD"
    },
    {
        key1: "XXX",
        key2: "YYY"
    },
]

const result = input.reduce( (acc,i) => {  
  const last = acc[acc.length-1];
  if(last === undefined || last.key2 != i.key1){
    acc.push({...i});      
  }
  else{
    acc[acc.length-1] = {...last, key2:i.key2};
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Right. My earlier attempt at `reduce` didn't work quite as expected. Any chance you could help me with an immutable version of your implementation? Anyways, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @AndréKrosby ok, updated to be immutable. Probably should have done that to start, was being lazy :)

Comment: @AndréKrosby and simplified slightly